# display 2 options side by side from array in gamemaker?

Tags: arrays, menu

Recently I purchased gamemaker and followed Shaun Spalding's menu tutorial to get set up, but I've come across something that I want to change with the code. In the tutorial the options from the array are positioned so that they are one above the other, however for my game I want them to be right next to each other so that option 1 can be positioned on the left side of the screen, and option 2 on the right side of the screen on the same 'line' (but still able to switch between selecting either).

This is what it looks like currently.
[image]

As you can see, they are above each other, when really I want them side by side.

This is the code I have:

'Create' Event:

```
instruction[0] = "Back";
instruction[1] = "Start Game";


space = 100;
ipos = 0;
```

'Step' Event:

```
var move = 0;
move -= max(keyboard_check_pressed(vk_left),keyboard_check_pressed(ord("A")),0);
move += max(keyboard_check_pressed(vk_right),keyboard_check_pressed(ord("D")),0);

if (move != 0)
{
    ipos += move;
    if (ipos < 0) ipos = array_length_1d(instruction) - 1;
    if (ipos > array_length_1d(instruction) - 1) ipos = 0;
}

var push;
push = max(keyboard_check_released(vk_enter),keyboard_check_released(vk_shift),keyboard_check_released(vk_space),0);
if (push == 1) scr_instructions();
```

'Draw' Event:

```
draw_set_halign(fa_left);
draw_set_valign(fa_middle);
draw_set_font(fnt_options);
draw_set_color(c_white);

var m;
for (m = 0; m < array_length_1d(instruction); m += 1)
{

    draw_text(x + space, y + (m * space),string(instruction[m]))

}

draw_sprite(sprite_index, -1, x + 16, y + ipos * space - 21);
```

Anyone know what I need to change to get this to work?

Comment: Please clarify: the code is in [game-maker language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/game-maker-language/info) ?

Comment: Yes, it is in the game-maker language.

Answer (score 0):

Your draw_text seems to increase the y coordinate for each iteration in the loop.

Try to increase x using m instead.

Example:

```
draw_text(x + (m * space), y + space,string(instruction[m]))
```

You will likely have to adapt the spacing to get desired look.

Easiest is probably to hard code the coordinates instead of using a loop.

Do the same with draw_sprite.

```
draw_sprite(sprite_index, -1, x + 16 + ipos * space, y - 21);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working however - it does put the words on the same line, but they overlap and are effectively 'stuck' together with the only spacing changed being the gap between the words and the draw_sprite image. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ok, what happens when you enter coordinates manually? Example (100, 100) and (500, 100) for the two text entries. When you have found coordinates that look good you can adapt the draw_sprite as well.

Comment: If I add one set of coordinates the two options still remain 'stuck' together - if I try to add multiple coordinates for each of them, I get the error 'number of arguments expected 3 got 0'. That when the code looks like this; draw_text((64,1400), (2000,1400),string(instruction[m])) . I've tried to separate them by using instruction[0] and instruction[1] to pinpoint them in the array, but I just get different variations of the same error.

Comment: You have to do one call to draw_text for each element in "instruction". So remove the for loop and do:
draw_text(100, 100,string(instruction[0]))
draw_text(500, 100,string(instruction[1]))